# I want to export amcharts from external button , but not working in IE

Tags: export, internet-explorer-11, amcharts

I am able to do it using Amexport.js which is working fine for Firefox and Chrome but it is giving an error in IE11.

```
var tmp = new AmCharts.AmExport(chart);
```

This method is giving error in IE11:

> XML5634: An attribute with the same name already exists on this
>   element. Line: 1, Column 171.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to use the old version of amCharts export.

I suggest you use the new [Export plugin](https://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/intro-exporting-charts/) for that.

The code to trigger image export from the API would be this:

```
function savePNG() {
  chart.export.capture({}, function() {
    this.toPNG( {}, function( data ) {
      this.download( data, "image/png", "amCharts.png" );
    } );
  });
}
```

Here's a [working example](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/39c6fcf9853a7caa0ff84da926b7296c).